# Extreme Newbie in terminal. trying to install these "extensions?"

Tags: terminal, iterm2, macos-monterey

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to install (extensions?) into iterm2.

```
Last login: Tue Mar 19 03:34:02 on ttys000
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/Downloads
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro Downloads % curl -o "Atom One Dark.itermcolors" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atom-one-dark-te
rminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Dark.itermcolorse/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    20  100    20    0     0    268      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   266
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro Downloads % curl -o "Atom One Light.itermcolors" httpss://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanbuchar/a
tom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Light.itermcolors
curl: (1) Protocol "httpss" not supported or disabled in libcurl
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro Downloads %  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanbuchar/a
tom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Light.itermcolors
zsh: no such file or directory: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanbuchar/a
zsh: no such file or directory: tom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Light.itermcolors
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro Downloads % curl -o "Atom One Light.itermcolors" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanbuchar/a
tom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One Light.itermcolors
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    20  100    20    0     0    243      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   246
zsh: no such file or directory: tom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One
newuser@apples-MacBook-Pro Downloads %
```

Tried a few changes.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?"  **NOT** telling what you want to do, please use [edit] to improve your question!  (and welcome to SO!)

Comment: "Protocol "httpss" not supported or disabled in libcurl" ??? Is this i new protocol?  (Please leave out all typo's in your question (as much as possible))

Answer (score 1):

```
# First command
curl -o "Atom One Dark.itermcolors" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Dark.itermcolors

# Second command
curl -o "Atom One Light.itermcolors" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanbuchar/atom-one-dark-terminal/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Light.itermcolors
```

Ensure you have the correct URLs and filenames, and these commands should work fine.

Comment: Beside the `404: Not Found` on the Dark one .... 

Comment: Thank you much!  I'm not certain, but I think that worked.

Comment: @smallchangejack43: Please **check** before saying that....... (**PLEASE**!, we have time enough  ...)